# Float addition operator in LaTeX?

Tags: math-mode, math-operators, unicode-math, mathtools

I need to get the +. sign (see the OCaml float addition operator) in LaTeX. However, when I try:

```
*$\mid h :: t  \-> h +. sumList(t)$ \\**
```

The output is as follows:

[image: Not where it is supposed to be!]

How can I make sure that the period is directly next to the addition sign, and not next to the function call?

Thanks in advance,

Jake

Comment: unrelated but use use `\mathit{sumList}` or better `\mathop{\mathit{sumList}` the math italic font you get from $sumList$ is designed to make it look _not_ like a word, but a product of variables

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`{+}` would make a mathord `+` without the binary operator spacing, so `{+}.` will be adjacent and `\mathbin{{+}.}` will give the result the spacing `+` normally has

Comment: There are two redundant braces. The `\mathbin{+.}` is sufficient.

Comment: @wipet true, but harder to build up in bits as part of the exposition.